# Qlikview Report Formatting

Tags: formatting, qlikview

I am trying to create a Qlikview report with our company theme incorporated. How do I make it so the margins are not white, but the color I want? And I am also interested in having our logo spread across the top of each page -- the issue I am having now is I have included a picture as header but it only spreads across the middle 1/3 of the top, so it is small and there is a lot of white space.

I have created a Qlikview theme with the color scheme of our company included in it, but I haven't been successful in applying it.

Thanks.

Comment: I tried the same and got the same results. The border of a report is white and there is nothing to change it. Even setting a theme does not work. And the header image has to fit into one of the 3 small header (footer) elements. It does not seem that you can change the formattiong of the header (footer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use line objects and format the way you like .

Regards,
Nadeem